# Formatting date while retrieving datetime column from database Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a column "create date" in the database table of the type DateTime, but my problem is that I want to show the retrieved datetime value in a particulat date format like "dd/mm/yyyy" how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a `DateTime` variable in diffrent formats, e.g if your variable is `dt` you can show it in `dd/mm/yyyy` Format by following command.

```
string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"
```

You can use it as following:

```
public class Project
{
   ...
   public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
   public string FormattedCreationDate
   {
      get
      {
         return string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", CreationDate);
      }
   }
}
```

You can find some more formats at [String Format for DateTime [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: I am doing something like this.
public List<Project> GetProjects()
        {
            var projects = new List<Project>();
            using (var database = new ProjectDatabase())
            {
                projects = database.Context.Projects.ToList();
            }
            return projects;
        }
One column of project entity is of type datetime. Now I want all the rows returned by this function return the datetime column as per my required date format.

Comment: Yeah something like that. Created a partial class of the same name as generated by EF and put almost same code that you have provided but in the GetProject function. Thanks